# Dell Inspiron 7720 reboots instead of waking from standby

Tags: laptop, sleep, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 17R SE (7720) running BIOS version A12. It runs Windows 8 and it has the following problem for a while now (which it didn't have when I first got it).

Every time I put Windows into standby (close the lid, it's in standby, the light blinks, etc.) and try to wake it up again, I hear the CD drive make a noise and 2-3 seconds later makes the noise again and decides to reboot instead of waking up. The same sequence (in the 2-3 seconds) also happens when I start the laptop.

I've already tried updating my BIOS to A13 and A16, but neither of them seem to work (the BIOS simply says it's still running A12).

Is this a known issue? Can I fix it myself, or do I need to get in contact with Dell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I would share the actual solution to this problem. I don't know why the problem occured, but I do know what solved it. Called up Dell and got a motherboard replacement. No more issues since.